# How to make a Cocoa Document-Based App launch with multiple different windows?

Tags: macos, cocoa, document-based

I have a document based app in cocoa with three xibs for different toolbox windows.  At app launch I would like the toolboxes to be visible very similar to Adobe Illustrator where the toolboxes are visible on either side.  To do this would I need to implement my own NSApplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when the document spawns, in its controller class (or the app delegate, dependent on who owns the toolbox windows) call `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` on each of the windows that you want to bring forward.